# Keeping inline style changes when dispatch is fired?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having a problem with inline style changes that are reset when my dispatch is finished, because the state is being re-rendered, despite the other functionality of my component is working (you can still see that the counter is not stopping).

Here's a demonstration of what I mean.

[image]

You can see that the orange bar of the left box vanishes when the orange bar of the right bar finishes (the animation ends). Essentially what I'm doing here is changing the `width` property in inline styles.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { useDispatch, connect } from "react-redux";
import { addProfessionExperience } from "../../actions/index";

import "./Professions.sass";

const timers = [];
const progressWidths = [];

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    const filterID = +ownProps.match.params.filter;
    const { professions, professionExperience } = state;

    return {
        professions: professions.find(item => item.id === filterID),
        professionExperience: professionExperience
    };
};

const produceResource = (dispatch, profession, sub, subRef) => {
    if(timers[sub.id]) return;

    /*
    * Begin the progress bar animation/width-change.
    */
    Object.assign(subRef.current[sub.id].style, {
        width: "100%",
        transitionDuration: `${sub.duration}s`
    });

    /*
    * Updates the progress text with the remaining time left until done.
    */
    let timeLeft = sub.duration;

    const timeLeftCountdown = _ => {
        timeLeft--;
        timeLeft > 0 ? setTimeout(timeLeftCountdown, 1000) : timeLeft = sub.duration;

        subRef.current[sub.id].parentElement.setAttribute("data-duration", timeLeft + "s");
    }

    setTimeout(timeLeftCountdown, 1000);

    /*
    * Dispatch the added experience from profession ID and sub-profession level.
    * We do not allow duplicate timers, only one can be run at a time.
    */
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
        Object.assign(subRef.current[sub.id].style, {
            width: "0%",
            transitionDuration: "0.2s"
        });

        dispatch(addProfessionExperience({ id: profession.id, level: sub.level }));

        delete timers[sub.id];
    }, sub.duration * 1000);

    timers[sub.id] = timer;
};

const isSubUnlocked = (professionMaxExperience, subLevel, professionExperience) => {
    if(professionExperience <= 0 && subLevel > 1) return false;

    return professionExperience >= getExperienceThreshold(professionMaxExperience, subLevel);
};

const getExperienceThreshold = (professionMaxExperience, subLevel) => (((subLevel - 1) * 1) * (professionMaxExperience / 10) * subLevel);

const ConnectedList = ({ professions, professionExperience }) => {
    const currentExperience = professionExperience.find(item => item.profession === professions.id);
    const subRef = useRef([]);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {
        subRef.current = subRef.current.slice(0, professions.subProfessions.length);
    }, [professions.subProfessions]);

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="list">
                <ul>
                    {professions.subProfessions.map(el => {
                        const unlocked = isSubUnlocked(
                                            professions.maxExperience, 
                                            el.level, 
                                            (currentExperience ? currentExperience.amount : 0)
                                        );

                        const remainingExperience = getExperienceThreshold(professions.maxExperience, el.level) - (currentExperience ? currentExperience.amount : 0);

                        return (
                            <li 
                                key={Math.random()} 
                                style={{ "opacity": unlocked ? "1" : "0.5" }}
                                >
                                <div className="sprite">
                                    <img alt="" src={`/images/professions/${el.image}.png`} />
                                </div>

                                <div className="caption">{el.name}</div>

                                <div 
                                    className="progress-bar" 
                                    data-duration={unlocked ? `${el.duration}s` : `${remainingExperience} XP to Unlock`} 
                                    data-identifier={el.id}
                                >
                                    <span ref={r => subRef.current[el.id] = r} ></span>
                                </div>

                                <div className="footer">
                                    <button 
                                        className="btn" 
                                        onClick={() => unlocked ? produceResource(dispatch, professions, el, subRef) : false}
                                    >
                                        {unlocked ? 
                                                `Click` : 
                                                <i className="fa fa-lock"></i>
                                        }
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        );
                    })}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

const List = connect(mapStateToProps)(ConnectedList);

export default List;
```

How can I make it so the orange bars persist on their own and not disappears when another one finishes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is that you're using `Math.random()` to generate your keys. Keys are what the virtual DOM uses to determine whether an element is the "same" as the one on a previous render. By using a random key, you're telling the virtual DOM that you want to spit out a brand new DOM element instead of reusing the prior one, which means the new one won't retain any of the side effects you placed on the original element. Read up on React's [reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) for more info on this.

Try to use keys that logically represent the thing you're rendering. In the case of your code, `el.id` looks like it may be a unique identifier for the subprofession you're rendering. Use that for the key instead of `Math.random()`.

Additionally, refs are going to make reasoning about your code really difficult. Rather than using refs to manipulate your DOM, use state manipulation and prop passing, and let React re-render your elements with the new attributes.

Comment: Thanks for the link about reconciliation! It was a great read and I do feel like I understand it a bit more now. Now when I recall it, `Math.random()` was a placeholder for the early stages of my development where I didn't have any unique identifiers available, after going over my code again and changing that, it behaves like I want it to.